# Pass comma separated number to IN clause in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which takes a varchar parameter called  P_LOCATIONS in Oracle. This locations parameter has location id's that are comma separated. In database locationId is a number.

Following sql query throws an Invalid number when there are more than one locations. I understand that because of comma its not able to convert a varchar into a number. How can I achieve this?

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE       GET_RAW_DATA
      (   P_LOCATIONS IN VARCHAR2, 
          Results   OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
        )AS 
        BEGIN

       select * from tableName where LOCATION_ID IN ( P_LOCATIONS);
      END GET_RAW_DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

The end result of what you are doing is this:

```
select * from tableName where LOCATION_ID IN ('1,2,3');
```

And what you need is this:

```
select * from tableName where LOCATION_ID IN (1,2,3);
```

So you can use this:

```
select * from tableName where LOCATION_ID in (
    select regexp_substr(P_LOCATIONS,'[^,]+{1}',1,level)
    from dual connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(P_LOCATIONS,'[^,]*')) + 1
);
```

Comment: I am very thankful to you. It worked perfect. Thanks a million.